# Weird behavior of jquery css function on Firefox and IE 11

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, internet-explorer-11

I was trying to do something really simple, and when I started to debug the code, I didn't know what was wrong until I saw it.
I couldn't believe that this simple function wouldn't work on Firefox or IE 11, but works on Chrome.

Imagine that i got this div element with 2 css classes in it.

```
<div id="box" class="class1 class2"></div>
```

Where class2 has a border-top property.

```
.class2 {
   border-top: 1px solid #626262;
}
```

Now I would like to see if this box div has any border-top property.

The first thing you think is:

```
$("#box").css("border-top")
```

Right? that would return the border-top property (if any).
Well, this works on Chrome, and returns the border-top property... in Firefox and IE 11 returns an empty string, how is this even possible?

Any idea on what is going wrong? or any other way to get it on all browsers?

Thanks in advance.

EDITED: Ended up doing something different that worked for me, nothing related to this. I just payed attention to the borders' width and i apply the values for the ones that had a width different than 0px. Makes more sense, since i had other default border styles coming for no reason with "0px none #000000".

Comment: Each browser has its own way to compute element style. Now, why don't you check for class instead? `if($("#box").hasClass('class2'))` or `$('#box.class2').callAnyMethod()`

Comment: I can't, this is dynamic, i don't know the classes that they can add to the dom element. That's why i need to check for the property itself directly.

Comment: Sounds like a xy problem. Maybe explain your issue better, why would you need to check for any computed style?

Comment: I even tried using javascript
window.getComputedStyle($("#box .class1")[0]).getPropertyValue("border-top") and didn't work either, wtf.

I need it since it has to be all dynamic, the designers are working on those templates and they can put whatever name they want to the classes, there are thousands of templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the jQuery docs for css:

`Retrieval of shorthand CSS properties (e.g., margin, background, border), although functional with some browsers, is not guaranteed. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered border-width, use: $( elem ).css( "borderTopWidth" ), $( elem ).css( "borderBottomWidth" ), and so on.`

[css() method](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

so basically, you'll have to look up what each browser uses for many properties using your original approach....or you can do as A. Wolff suggested and just check for class instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching for a more atomic CSS property (ie, a non-zero "border-top-width" instead of "border-top")?

Comment: I've not run across this before, but it sounds like browsers (or jQuery's translation to browser-specifics CSS properties) just don't support searching for complex css properties very consistently.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the computed value for a single value property like `border-top-width` but for a multi-value property like `border-top` there are differences with the browsers, both with jquery as well as the DOM API:

```js
for (var properties = ['border-top', 'border-top-width'], i = 0, l = properties.length; i < l; i++) {
  console.log(properties[i] + ': ' + $('#box').css(properties[i]));
  console.log(properties[i] + ': ' + window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('box')).getPropertyValue(properties[i]));
  }
```

```css
.class2 {
   border-top: 1px solid #626262;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" class="class1 class2">This is a test.</div>
```

Comment: Have you seen that this won't show in console the border-top in Firefox but it's showing up in Chrome? only showing the border-top-width in FF.

Comment: Yes, it is meant to demonstrate that there are differences, both in the `getComputedStyle` as well as the `css` method (which probably relies on `getComputedStyle`). So as long as you check `border-top-width`, you should get a consistent result, for shorthand properties not.

Comment: yea, im f*cked up, i was needing that border-color :(